# Short TOC without List of Tables/Figures and Appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, shorttoc

I have two tables of contents, a short one and a detailed one. In the short one, I do not want the List of Figures, List of Tables, and Appendices listed. In the long one, I would like it all listed. How can I 'delete' the lists and appendices from the short toc?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}

\begin{document}

\shorttoc{Contents (short)}{1} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}

\bibliographystyle{mine}
\bibliography{library}

\printindex

\appendix
\input{appendix1}
\input{appendix2}
\input{appendix3}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, i.e. one without `\input` statements -- we don't have the files you have on your computer, nor do we have `library.bib`. It is also missing `makeidx` or `imakeidx` package

Comment: Please note also, that `shorttoc` is almost 15 years old and its author, J.P. Drucbert died in 2009 unfortunately, so this package is not maintained. You could use `minitoc` (also by J. Drucbert) or `etoc`

Comment: The real culprit is that `tocbibind` adds the full information to the `.toc`, and `shorttoc` evaluates this

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation. As it turned out, I am not allowed to leave out the Lists and Appendices in my short TOC, so the question solved itself in a way. I think it is best not to work with shorttoc in general. Unfortunately I started with my thesis eons ago and am now struggling with not being uptodate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small workaround, by writing a separate toc and using `\ifshowinshorttoc`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newif\ifshowinshorttoc



\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{
\let\l@tex@ddcontentsline\addcontentsline

\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
  \l@tex@ddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{toc}%
  \ifshowinshorttoc
  \l@tex@ddcontentsline{stoc}{#2}{#3}%
  \fi
  \fi
}
}

\newcommand{\shorttoc}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \@starttoc{stoc}
}

\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{\showinshorttocfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\shorttoc{Contents (short)}%{1} 
\showinshorttoctrue
\tableofcontents
\showinshorttocfalse
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\showinshorttoctrue
\chapter{Foo}
%\input{chapter1}
%\input{chapter2}
%\input{chapter3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{biblio}

%\printindex

\appendix

\chapter{Foo appendix}
%\input{appendix1}
%\input{appendix2}
%\input{appendix3}


\end{document}
```